# Join Two Databases in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join, inner-join, multiple-databases

I need your help. I have two databases (ex. PEN and PAPER) the tables of which need to be joined. Table name in db PEN is PEN.ORDER. Table name in db PAPER is PAPER.ORDER.

Being on PAPER db I am doing

```
SELECT SUPPLIER_NAME 
  FROM PAPER.ORDER AS A
 INNER JOIN PEN.PEN.ORDER AS B 
    ON A.SUPPLIER_ID=B.SUPPLIER_ID
```

It does not see the table from PEN Database. Tried to write PEN."PEN.ORDERS" and PEN.[PEN.ORDERS] but nothing helped.

But when I tried similar thing with a different database, where a table name did not contain a dot, it worked very well. Being in PAPER db It was like:

```
SELECT SUPPLIER_NUMBER 
  FROM PAPER.ORDER AS A 
 INNER JOIN BOOK.ORDERS AS B 
    ON A.SUPPLIER_NUMBER=B.SUPPLIER_NUMBER
```

Here it worked since the table name in BOOK db was just ORDERS without any second word separated by dot.

Comment: Do you get an error message? You should do, because that's not valid syntax for Oracle.

Comment: Are you certain that you are using "database" in the Oracle sense of the word?  `pen.order` in Oracle refers to an `order` table in the `pen` schema and `paper.order` refers to an `order` table in the `paper` schema.  Both schemas would be in the same database just different schemas.  If you really mean that they are in separate databases, you'd need a database link between the two databases.

Comment: But when I tried similar thing with a different database, where table names did not contain a dot, it worked very well. Being in PAPER db It was like: SELECT SUPPLIER_NUMBER FROM PAPER.ORDER AS A INNER JOIN BOOK.ORDERS AS B ON A.SUPPLIER_NUMBER=B.SUPPLIER_NUMBER        In this case I did not have any issue. BOOK was a different database, which I connected to and the table name was just ORDERS.

Comment: you still seem to not understand the difference between a 'database' and a 'schema'.  In oracle, a table name  _does not and cannot_ contain a dot.  It sounds to me like you are taking a MS SQL Server understanding to oracle.  That won't work.  The very definition of 'database' is different.  What is commonly referred to as a 'database' in mssql is a 'schema' (a collection of objects owned by a user) in Oracle.  Please re-read previous comment by @Justin Cave

Comment: PL/SQL is **not** a name for Oracle database, or for Oracle SQL. I won't even bore you with what it **is** - just don't use that name to refer to Oracle SQL. I will edit your post accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. I am relatively new in Oracle SQL. So, if I have different schemas, how can I join those tables if their names contain dots?

Answer (score 1):

What you call a "database" is "user" in Oracle.

You said that this doesn't work when you're connected as `PAPER`:

```
SELECT SUPPLIER_NAME 
  FROM PAPER.ORDER AS A
 INNER JOIN PEN.PEN.ORDER AS B 
    ON A.SUPPLIER_ID=B.SUPPLIER_ID
```

> Table name in db PEN is PEN.ORDER. Table name in db PAPER is PAPER.ORDER.

If you want to be able to fetch data that belongs to other user (`PEN` in this case), table owner has to grant you (at least) `SELECT` privilege on its table. So: connect as `PEN` and run

```
grant select on order to paper;
```

Then connect as `PAPER` again and run

```
select a.supplier_name
from order a join pen.order b on a.supplier_id = b.supplier_id;
```

Note several changes I made:

- tables' aliases don't have `as` keyword (it is not `order as a` but `order a`)
- `PEN`'s table is preceded with its owner name, only once (it is not `pen.pen.order` but `pen.order`)

---

**However**: there's something strange with your tables. `order` is an invalid name in Oracle:

```
SQL> create table order (id number);
create table order (id number)
             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00903: invalid table name
```

If it really used that name, then it has been created with double quotes, e.g.

```
SQL> create table "order" (id number);

Table created.
```

But, you can't select from it *just like that*:

```
SQL> select * From order;
select * From order
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00903: invalid table name
```

Nope - you have to use double quotes, always, matching letter case, always:

```
SQL> select * From "order";

no rows selected
```

Suggestion: don't use reserved/keywords for object names. Don't use double quotes in Oracle, ever (not that it won't work - it will, as you see, but it is really painful).

Answer (score 0):

If your table is named PEN.ORDER in schema PEN then enclose it within double quotes like the below. Also, remove AS from the table Alias

```
     SELECT A.SUPPLIER_NAME 
     FROM PAPER.ORDER  A
     INNER JOIN PEN."PEN.ORDER" B 
     ON A.SUPPLIER_ID=B.SUPPLIER_ID
```